# Drag drop URL into a Swing panel

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to capture the URL of a link dragged from any browser into a Java Swing based panel?

I am building an application where such ability (to capture links based on what users drag and drop) greatly enhances the ease of use.

I noticed that Java 7 supports drag and drop of files in a simpler manner, but am not sure how to use that for capturing dragged links.

Comment: Absolutely, the best solution might be register a component as `DropTarget` and interrogate the `DataFlavour` of the dropped object...

Comment: Dragging links works just like dragging text. The simplest solution is to create a text field, you can drag links into it without any additional effort.